# Reading 40 MB ORC file is taking 20 minutes on spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading ORC file of 40 mb from OCI object storage in to simple spark job. 
File is getting loaded but is taking 20 minute to produce the result.
I see same log snippet is getting repeated for driver and executor logs every one minute[please refer attached logs below.]
Looks like ORC file getting loaded in batch of records ?
Any help would be appreciated?

**Total records count** : 108550083

**EX record** : Row(s1='vezpoxvqtgmdtwn', dt='1995-09-06 01:42:54', i1=210608706, s2='19.111.163.61', s3='xchxtfljgfcmposjwml'),

***Code***

```
parser.add_argument("--input", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--output", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Convert ORC to Parquet").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("orc").load(args.input)
df.show()
```

**Driver log** : 
[image]
**Executor log** :
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How many records are there in that orc file ? And also post spark ui screen shot ?

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas for looking in to the issue.Same has been updated.

Comment: I think you are getting data from object store & it has huge records (don't consider orc file size), Do you have any partitions in object store ? Your spark performance is depending on data stored in object store.

Comment: Can you show executor tab ?

Comment: `spark-submit` command please ... looks like you are using one driver and one executor you need to increase the number of executors and its memory  based on work load or go for dynamical allocation.  if you give less resourecs ORC will load in batch wise with less data to complete the orc processing.

Comment: If you have multiple partitions on object store your data will be loaded parallel.

Comment: Thanks all for looking in to the issue.
Setting 'spark.sql.orc.impl' to 'hive' solve the issue

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.orc.impl", "hive").appName("Convert ORC to Parquet").getOrCreate()

Comment: More information :
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=orc#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.orc

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-orc.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the SparkUI when the code is running, this will help get a deeper understanding. An example screen is attached.

It looks you have sufficient memory considering the file size you are dealing with and it should not be an issue or alternatively you can specify the driver memory and executor memory

[image]